# Xcelsius XML Data connection using .aspx page Error #2032

Tags: asp.net, xml, flash, xcelsius

Because of my version of Xcelsius I'm limited to 2 web service connections so I tried using XML Data connection and aspx page to bring data from database to Xcelsius.
I have an ASPX page that outputs an xml file with the format

```
<data><variable name=""><row><column></column>...</row></variable>...</data>
```

In Xcelsius I made a XML Data connection having the XML URL pointing to the .aspx page that should output an xml. Then I have the Enable Load checked and I have selected the proper # of cells and rows . If I try preview I get

```
"An error has occurred. For more information, contact the file creator or your
system administrator. 
Error: Error #2032 Connection Type: XML Data".
```

I have the crossdomain.xml file on both the application folder and IIS wwwroot folder that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-        policy.dtd">  
<cross-domain-policy>  
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />  
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>  
</cross-domain-policy>
```

If I put in the XML URL in Xcelsius, the url to the xml file directly without using .aspx to write it to the output of the page it works. The xml is in the same application folder as .aspx page.
My scope is to use the .aspx page to write query on the database and output back an xml with the table in the correct xml format so I can then consume the data in Xcelsius.

Does anybody know how to fix the error or other ways I can bring data from database into Xcelsius?

My version of Xcelsius: Engage 5.4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solutions is embed your dashboard inside a pdf. Then access and format (and write-back) your XML query via Acrobat.  It's how I do it.

1. Embed your resources.
2. Contact the .aspx via PDF.
3. Write the result under _global
4. Link to static XML inside the PDF.

Be SURE to embed your resources. You can figure out how via AcrobatX documentation under flash integration
.
It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it works a charm so long as your can tolerate the PDF object in your project.

--Gary

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the exact same configuration. However, I'm using "Flash Variables" for my data connection and the data is generated every time you hit the ASP page in XML - Flash Variables format.

I've just tested my ASP page to generate in XML format and used and XML connection in xcelius and it works perfectly fine.

***My suggestion is to try changing MIME type in Xcelsius XML Connection to "text/xml"***